# PHP Rand function seems to be weighted

Tags: php, random

I am using the following code to test a function I have, but it seems like the rand function is generating weighted results:

```
$D22[] = rand(1,2)*10+rand(1,2);
```

Testing this is generating one of four numbers: 11,12,21,22.  It should be running about 25% each, but 11 is actually only showing up about 5% of the time (only ran it 20 times).

What is causing this, and is there a better random function for PHP?

P.S.: I know this question is probably not valid for reasons. :)

Answer (score 0):

u can use `mt_rand()`

see this link 
[mt_rand vs rand](https://en.code-bude.net/2013/01/06/php-rand-vs-mt_rand-what-is-more-accurate-what-is-faster/)

Comment: it should be a comment though :

Comment: I just found my error.  It was re-rolling values of 11.  However, thanks for the suggestion.  I will use it!

Comment: in PHP 7, we should use cryptographically secure `random_int`